give input to specific sink pads of an element
Im working on custom gstreamer plugin where it has 2 sinkpads
how to connect a filesrc to a specific sinkpad
       filesrc1----------|
                         |----> custom_plugin------->filesink
       filesrc2----------|

here my custom_plugin have 2 sinkpads sink_1 and sink_2
while building pipeline using gst-launch-1.0 how to link filesrc1 to sink_1 and filesrc2 to sink_2
both sink_1 and sink_2 have different chain events and sink_2 pushes buffer to src pad
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=left.avi ! decodebin  ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=BGR,width=1920,height=1080 ! custom_plugin.sink_1 ! filesrc location=right.avi ! decodebin  ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=BGR,width=1920,height=1080 ! custom_plugin.sink_2 ! fakesink
this is what is I tried and below is the
WARNING: erroneous pipeline: syntax error
what im trying to figure is how to if a plugin have multiple sinkpads how to connect a specific sinkpad

The issue could be caused by not directly calling the plugin into the pipeline and just trying to use the sinks directly. Try including the plugin into the pipeline and then sending the stream to the sinks:
gst-launch-1.0 custom_plugin name=cp filesrc location=left.avi ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=BGR,width=1920,height=1080 ! cp.sink_1  filesrc location=right.avi ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=BGR,width=1920,height=1080 ! cp.sink_2 ! fakesink

Also I noticed that you have 2 filesrc in the same pipeline which could be causing the syntax error. Remove the pipe symbol (!) before the second filesrc
